# Как в mysql внести данные так, чтобы заполнился не весь столбец, а только одна строчка

Tags: php, mysql

```
$res = $mysql->query("UPDATE `result` SET checked = checked + 1");
```

В этом запросе естестевенно заполнятся весь столбец **checked**.
Но можно ли сделать такой запрос, чтобы например заполнить поле **checked** допустим только у **красной** команды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте в документации про ключевое слово `WHERE`.

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему, после прочтения документации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE `result` SET checked = checked + 1 WHERE team = 'Красная'
```